# windows phone splash screen don't take full screen

Tags: windows-phone-8

I followed the instructions from http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/iersoy/creating-splash-screens-in-windows-phone-8-apps/ . And when I launched my simple app, the slash screen showed. However, It does not cover the top region,where network status and time get shown. Could anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the XAML at the top of your page set the following property to false:

```
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False"
```

Answer (score 1):

You Should take Popup and image sizes as 768 x 1280 that are universal size for Splash Screen and set in all Resolution, if it doesnt work, You Should go as mentioned below :

To display a splash screen for all resolutions, use a single image file named `SplashScreenImage.jpg` that is `768 × 1280`. The phone automatically scales the image to the correct size.
If you want to provide pixel-perfect splash screens for all resolutions, you can add images with the following file names:

```
SplashScreenImage.Screen-WVGA.jpg
SplashScreenImage.Screen-WXGA.jpg
SplashScreenImage.Screen-720p.jpg
```

Windows Phone 8 Update 3 will default to using the 720p splash screen file on a 1080p phone.

Important Note:

```
All splash screen images must be in the root folder of your app project.
```

For more info, see [How to create a splash screen for Windows Phone.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769511%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)